# Admob Not showing ads on real devices only showing on Test devices only

Tags: android, admob

```
 private void showInterstitialadd() {

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

        // set the ad unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

                .build();

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads

        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }
```

I am using the above function for showing Ads....and its working absolutely fine on my test device but when I remove that .addTestdevice().....and run on any other devices it does not shows up....

Comment: It will take time to show ads in real device like one -  two hour

Comment: Have you see the logcat? Usually there is a message if something is happen with ads.

Comment: W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

Comment: its was working fine in the previous versions too...

Comment: chk your admob id

Answer (score 0):

There may be no issue in your code but AdMob doesn't show ads on real device quickly. You have to wait for few days. Before that, you have to enter some details like address and payment account detail in your AdMob account. 
Don't worry they guide via email. 
After you enter details, wait for few days, you will be notified in AdMob account that ads are showing.

In my case, it takes 2 days and, only Banner and Interstitial ads were activated at that time and video ads still do not get loaded.

So if ads are showing on test device then it will also be showing in the real device. The only thing you have to do is complete AdMob account setup and wait.
Also, don't forget to remove `.addTestdevice()` code before checking on real device.